# canvas.toDataUrl is not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to get base64 data from image. So what I am doing is, creating new canvas element then drawing image whos base64 is needed, then get base64 data from canvas using canvas.toDataUrl function.

But in return of canvas.toDataUrl i am getting ==> data:,
This is working fine on web browser but not on android emulator or phone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src="images/splash.png";
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var rectWidth = $(window).width();
    var rectHeight = 100;
    canvas.width = rectWidth;
    canvas.height = rectHeight;

    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var myImage1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");      // Get the data as an image.
        $("#MyPix").attr('src', myImage1); 
        $('#canvasDiv').append(myImage1);
    }
    $('#canvasDiv').append(canvas);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's possible that toDataUrl isn't supported in the Android browser on your version of Android. What version is it you are trying to get this to work on?